# How can I disable transit layer on Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

In Google maps, the transit layer is by default shown. I want to be able to disable that, like it is possible in Google Maps app.

I cant find the option to do that. I've see the options for traffic, indoor, buildings but no option for transit or bicycle layers.

Comment: "transit layer" means public transport stops or something else?

Comment: By transport layer I mean the metro/subway tracks which show on the map

Comment: You can use [map styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide transit layer (transit markers) via [custom map style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling). You can use [wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)  for create your own map style with hidden transit markers:

[image: Hide transit via wizard]

then copy-paste JSON into `map_style.xml` file to `raw` folder of your project:

[image: Copy xml]

then apply map style to your map:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.map_style));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be disabled, but it can be hidden away, see: [Hiding Map Features with Styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/hiding-features).

You'd just have to find out which `featureType` to style ...

```
transit                 // selects all transit stations and lines.
transit.line            // selects transit lines.
transit.station         // selects all transit stations.
transit.station.airport // selects airports.
transit.station.bus     // selects bus stops.
transit.station.rail    // selects rail stations.
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I'm creating a new style here. https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Never knew this was possible. This is a game changer for me! Thank you Martin!